# Ionic app crashes on start with no code changes

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic app which says "stopped working" instantly after open it in mobile.

I don't know what's happening because it was working well. If I run it in browser it still working, but in mobile it's not working.

I run:

```
$ionic cordova run android
```

I already tried to remove and add the android platform, deleted node_modules and plugins folder and it still failing.

**Additional info:**

`$ionic cordova requirements`:

```
Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-19,android-18

Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
```

`$ionic info`:

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.14.4
    npm               : 3.10.10 
    OS                : Linux 4.4

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /home/ivan/Android

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried running ionic cordova run android --debug --consolelogs? There could be a multitude of issues, mainly regarding the plugins.

Comment: Hello @StephenRomero . Thank's for replying. I tried with the `--debug` flag and I have no errors. The console says "LAUNCH SUCESS" but in my mobile, when the app attempts to start, it shows an alert saying "App has stopped". 
It does not even show the splashcreen. It occurs before of that.

Comment: So I came across this issue with my android device but it was a different issue. My app would build just fine and as soon as I ran it on my tablet I would get an error saying connection refused. The app would then close out. The only solution I found was to completely remove the android platforms and all of the plugins and then re-install. You may also try updating your plugins. You can check your current versions and newest versions running npm outdated in the console. Then using npm update "package name".

Comment: Are you sure that you were using `android@7.0.0` when the app was working fine? If not, what happens if you uninstall android `ionic cordova platform remove android` and then install `android@6.4.0` for example via `ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0`?

Comment: @StephenRomero Thank you for your help! I am trying that.

Comment: @sebaferreras Yes, it was working fine with `cordova-android@7.0.0`. I needed to upgrade that dependency in order to install batch plugin a while ago and it was working fine. The last friday, it was working when I tried FCM and PushWoosh plugins but it was in another branch. Now master doesn't work. I tried removing the entire platform, deleting node_modules, plugins, and re-installing them but it's still failing.

Comment: Well, it seems like it's an issue with the batch plugin. Because if I uninstall it, the app works, and it fails when I download it again. But I don't know why because it was working and I didn't updated anything from the last week.

Comment: Use chrome to remote debug (chrome://inspect) and see what JS errors are detected... You need some additionnal insights here.